# Exclude addon domain from rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, dns, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect all files in the folder mydomain.com/es to mydomain.com/
This works using

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/es/ /index.php
```

However this is also redirecting the folder es/ in one of my addon domains.
So myaddondomain.com/es/ is going to mydomain.com/

How do I stop this? I have searched through the forum and found these rules that people have posted, but neither of them work

```
RewriteRule ^myaddondomain.com/?$ - [L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myaddondomain.com/$
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts. Could you please post your complete htaccess rules file in your question.

Comment: "So myaddondomain.com/es/ is going to mydomain.com/" - The above would redirect `myaddondomain.com/es/` to `myaddondomain.com/index.php` (preserving the domain name), not `mydomain.com/` - so maybe there is something else going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RedirectMatch 302 ^/es/ /index.php
> ```

If this should only apply to a particular domain (ie. *hostname*) then you need to use mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule` / `RewriteCond`) instead and check the `HTTP_HOST` in a *condition*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^es/ /index.php [R,L]
```

Note that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (1st argument) in a *directory* context does not start with a slash.

This also allows for an optional www subdomain. Remove `(www\.)?` in the *CondPattern* if that is not required.

Note that this redirects to `/index.php`, not strictly `mydomain.com/` as you stated in your description. Maybe you should be redirecting to `/` instead?

*Aside:* As far as SEO is concerned, many-to-one redirects to the homepage will likely be seen as a soft-404.

---

*Aside:*

> I have searched through the forum and found these rules that people have posted, but neither of them work
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^myaddondomain.com/?$ - [L]
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myaddondomain.com/$
> ```

I would be curious *where* you saw these (on StackOverflow?) as they are obviously incorrect in this context.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (first rule) matches against the URL-path only, so the first rule will never match.

Again, the `REQUEST_URI` server variable (second rule) contains the URL-path only so the "negated" *condition* will always be successful.

Comment: This was very helpful - thank you. The page redirects - leaving the original url in the url bar. The only thing was the images and style sheet didn't show - so i made them absolute urls and now they do.

Comment: @user1800520 "The page redirects - **leaving the original url in the url bar**." - This would imply you've implemented an internal "rewrite", not an (external) "redirect" (as stated in the question). So, presumably, you have removed the `R` flag on the `RewriteRule` directive? In which case, rewriting to `index.php` (as opposed to simply `/` as suggested in my answer) would be correct. And yes, you will need to use absolute or root-relative URLs to your static resources if you are _rewriting_ (not redirecting) to a different URL-path depth.